# Linq to Entity having more than one where conditions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

How can I check for more than one condition in the where clause of LINQ to Entities?

How can I check if the value is false or null

```
.Where(p => (p.Disabled == false || p.Disabled = null));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine conditions using the usual Boolean operators.

Your solution is missing `==` in the second part of the condition:

```
.Where(p => (p.Disabled == false || p.Disabled == null));
//                    Here --------------------^
```

You can simplify this further, because checking for a nullable `bool` to be `false` or `null` is equivalent to checking for it not being `true`:

```
.Where(p => p.Disabled != true);
```

Comment: .Where(p => (p.Disabled == null ? false:p.Disabled)==false ); I found a  workaround for my solution, But yes you are right.

Comment: @JohnTurner C# has a better operator this: `(p.Disabled ?? false)` is the same as `(p.Disabled == null ? false:p.Disabled)`.

Comment: .Where(p => p.Disabled != true); This doesn't work as I guess the compiler converts "!=true" to "false", and it doesn't return the null rows.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight.